# How do I know if a Binomial model is appropriate?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, binomial-theorem

I have a question which is about the number of weeks out of 5 in which an event occurs. I have a frequency table with a sample of 40 - with x = 0,1,2,3,4,5 and freq, 2,7,11,12,6,2.

I have worked out the unbiased population mean and estimate - but then I'm not sure whether binomial what I need or not? I have to decide if a bionomial model is appropriate.

I can see that the data is discrete but its not binary like "event happens" or "event does not happen". It seems relatively symmetrical - and almost normally distributed? I'm not really sure how to work this out? Is a binomial model right or not?

Comment: Given the mean and the numbers (40 events in 5 cases) the binary model can be computed explicitly.  See how closely your data is matched.

Comment: "Is a binomial model right or not?" is not answerable but you can show it is not significantly different from what you might get from a binomial distribution with parameters $n=5$ and $p=0.495$ or $0.5$

Answer (score 1):

If this is your first chi-squared test, the clues in the comments may be a bit too sparse. Without working the problem for you, I offer the following
more complete outline:  (Use it along with whatever
examples your text or class notes may have to offer.)

It is appropriate to try a binomial model, and obviously $n = 5.$
From the given data you can find the sample mean
of the 40 observations. Setting that equal to the
binomial mean $np$ you can get @Henry's estimate
$\hat p = 0.495.$

By looking at the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(5, 0.495).$
you can find the expected counts $E_i.$ (multiply the probabilities by 40.) Your observed counts are $F = (2,7,11,12,6,2).$

Next, you can find the chi-squared statistic
$Q =\sum_{i=0}^5 \frac{(F_i - E_i)^2}{E_i},$ which
is approximately distributed as $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=4).$
[Ordinarily, a chi-squared test with 6 categories
would have $\nu = 6-1 = 5,$ but you have used the
data to estimate parameter $p,$ so you 'lose' a
degree of freedom for that and $\nu = 4.]$

I got $Q =  1.1815.$ The critical value for
a chi-squared test with $\nu = 4$ at the 5% level
is the 95th percentile $c = 9.487$ of $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu=4).$ You can find this number in printed tables
of the chi-squared distribution or using software (as with R below).

```
qchisq(.95, 4)
9.487729
```

This means that you would reject the null hypothesis
that the data are consistent with $\mathsf{Binom}(n=5, p=0.495)$ only if $Q \ge c =  9.487.$

There is one remaining difficulty. The chi-squared
test is usually deemed to be accurate only if all
expected counts exceed 5. Your first and last $E_i$s
are too small. One cure for this is to combine 'categories' $0$ and $1$, and 'categories' $4$ and $5.$
In each tail, combine categories by adding the two observed frequencies and adding the two expected frequencies.

You will now have four categories and $\nu = 4-1 -1=2$ degrees of freedom. Re-compute $Q$ and find the new $c$ (as below). [According to my computations, you will still not reject $H_0.]$

```
qchisq(.95, 2)
[1] 5.991465
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I'm just wondering WHY n is 5 and not 6 as the case of 0 faults is a case as well?

Comment: A binomial random variable with $n=5$ can have six outcomes $0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5.$  If you are trying to see if counts match such a variable, using a chi-squared test, you need begin by considering each possible outcome as a category. {Then if you have a small amount of data, you may need to combine adjacent categories later in order for the chi-squared test to be valid--as in my last two paragraphs.}